# Finding all .cpp and .h files and moving them to ~/junk

Tags: find

I created a folder on my home directory call junk, and let's say I want to move all .cpp and .h files to it. How would I do it? My first thought is to start with find ~ -name *.cpp -print, but I don't know how to put in multiple patterns into the find argument, and I'm fairly lost after that.

Answer (score 2):

If on a GNU system, you can use the `-regex` option to `find` as shown below:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(h\|cpp\)" -exec echo mv -v "{}" ~/junk \;
```

the output will show which command would be executed, like a dry run. If that looks good, you can remove the `echo` for applying.

**Command Break Down**

- `-regex`  : File name matches regular expression pattern, the default regex type it's uses `emacs`
- `".*\.\(h\|cpp\)"` : Since it's uses default regex type `emacs`, as per pattern match `.` (dot) means matches any character so to match exact `.` ( dot), we have to use escape character that is `\`. means for special character like `(`, `|` we have to use escape character. the pattern  same as `.*.(h|cpp)` (regextype posix-egrep )
- `-exec` : Execute command
- `{ }` : The string { } replaced by the matches file name
- `\;` : Needs to be there as it tells the end of arguements provided to -exec variable

For more information on regular expression you can refer

- `man 7 regex`
- [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Comment: can you break down what ".*\.\(h\|cpp\)" means? I'm a beginner so I'm completely lost.

Comment: @JonathanChiou See the updated answer..

Answer (score 2):

portably:

```
cd &&
  find . -path ./junk -prune -o -type f \( \
    -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec sh -c '
      exec mv -i "$@" junk' sh {} +
```

Above excluding the `junk` folder itself from the search.

We're only removing *regular* files (`-type f`). There may be other types of files you want to move like symlinks, but beware that moving symlinks often break them.

The `-i` is a safeguard to avoid two files with the same name overriding each other.

Comment: please once check my updated answer, I think I have wrongly explain regex part

Comment: Could you please explain the extra calls to `sh`? As opposed to for instance `find . ! -path './junk/*' -type f \( -name '*.h' -o '*.cpp' \) -exec mv -i "{}" ./junk/ \;`

Comment: @grebneke, `mv -i {} junk \;` would run one `mv` per file. Using `+` means pass as may files as possible. You need `sh` to be able to have a `junk` argument after that list. With GNU or FreeBSD `mv`, you could have done `-exec mv -it junk {} +` instead.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I see, but there are *two* `sh`, what does the second one do `sh {} +`?

Comment: @grebneke, the first argument after `sh -c code` is for `$0` (used for error messages...), `"$@"` starts after.

Answer (score 0):

According to `pinfo bash`*->Shell Expansions->Filename Expansion->3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching*, the ‘extglob’ shell option may be enabled using the ‘shopt’ builtin. Apparently, `Cargo`, Rust's package manager and build tool also enables this in their bash completion script with `shopt -s extglob`. So my shell already recognizes several extended pattern matching operators. Lists of patterns can separated by a ‘|’.

> ‘?(PATTERN-LIST)’
> Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
>
> ‘*(PATTERN-LIST)’
> Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> ‘+(PATTERN-LIST)’
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
>
> ‘@(PATTERN-LIST)’
> Matches one of the given patterns.
>
> ‘!(PATTERN-LIST)’
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

So we can do something like this.

```
mkdir -p ~/junk
for name in *.?(h|cpp); do echo mv -- "${name}" ~/junk/; done

mv -- ggml-alloc.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-backend.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-backend-impl.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-cuda.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-impl.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-metal.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-mpi.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-opencl.cpp ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-opencl.h ~/junk/
mv -- ggml-quants.h ~/junk/
mv -- llama.cpp ~/junk/
mv -- llama.h ~/junk/
mv -- unicode.h ~/junk/
```

And then remove the `echo`, if it purports to do what we want...